# Should I opt for C# 7.0 tuples over `out`?

Tags: c#, coding-style, c#-8.0, c#-7.0

```
public Task<User> Register(User user, string password) 
{
    byte[] passwordHash, passwordSalt;
    CreatePasswordHash(password, out passwordHash, out passwordSalt);

    user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
    user.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;

    return user;
}

public void CreatePasswordHash(string password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt) 
{
    using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512())
    {
        passwordSalt = hmac.Key;
        passwordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
    }
}
```

or tuple:

```
public Task<User> Register(User user, string password) 
{
    byte[] (passwordHash, passwordSalt) = CreatePasswordHash(password, passwordHash, passwordSalt);

    user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
    user.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;

    return user;
}

public (byte[], byte[]) CreatePasswordHash(string password, byte[] passwordHash, byte[] passwordSalt) 
{
    using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512())
    {
        passwordSalt = hmac.Key;
        passwordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));

        return (passwordSalt, passwordHash);
    }
}
```

I'm currently using the code above and it makes use of `out` keywords. In this situation would it be preferred to make use of the C# 7.0 value tuple rather than using the `out` keyword?

Comment: This is going to be a matter of opinion. Do what your code standard dictates, if you have one; otherwise, do what you feel is easier to understand.  Optimize for readability, whatever that is for you (and/or your team).

Comment: Aren't there common guidelines / recommendations when it comes to `out` by Microsoft?

Comment: There are, but none of them cover `out` vs. tuples.

Comment: I don't believe Microsoft is adding new APIs that use tuples to .NET Core, but that's just a long-shot guess by me, and that is by no means supposed to be guidance for your own code.

Comment: why not return a `Dictionary` instead ? if you used it, then there is no need for the `out` arguments, and if you're planning to have more `out`, I would suggest to create a class to hold them, and just return the class.

Comment: I personally prefer `out` since the tuple function returns two `byte[]` but you have to look at the definition to see which one is the password/salt.

Comment: The reason for me asking this question is because, I'm relatively new to C#, and many the sources I have been learning C# from do recommend to avoid `out` when possible.

Comment: Since you're new, I suggest that you learn each version of C# in order. There are nuances that are much easier to understand if you do and you'll get a better feel for how to use `out` and tuples effectively.

Comment: In general I find that if a method needs to return more than one value, and the values are related to each other, then it makes sense to write a class that has properties for the values and return an instance of the class (note that this does not apply to methods like `TryParse` that return a "success" value as well as assign a value to some `out` parameter, since those two values are not directly related). If it returns more than one value and the values aren't related, then it probably should be split into two methods.

Comment: In your case, I'd return an instance of `class HashSalt { public byte[] Hash {get; set;} public byte[] Salt {get; set;} }`

Answer (score 1):

They are almost the same thing.

```
if (int.TryParse(text, out var value))
```

is more easy on the eye than

```
var (success, value) = int.TryParse(text);
if (success)
```

But if you method is asynchronous, you can't escape it

```
var (success, value) = await int.TryParseAsync(text);
if (success)
```

In the future, you might be able to do something like this:

```
if (var (success, value) = int.TryParse(text); success)
```

but not for the time being..